# Enable Distraction Free Reading Mode in Chrome based on Website Domain

Tags: chrome, google-apps

Is there a chrome extension, that enables distraction free reading mode in Google Chrome based on the website domain?

I frequently visit some website and would like to enable reading mode without manually enabling it. I had come across such extension long time ago. But I can't find it, I did some research and found about Readability and other similar extensions, but can't find the one that does it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I already have [uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en) installed anyway, and I've been using the "element picker" tool to turn off distracting sidebars on sites I visit frequently (such as "Hot Network Questions" on StackExchange).

- Fewer extensions installed = better security (you should be using an ad blocker, anyway)
- Turn off exactly what you want to
- Settings are specific for sites, and always turned on

It doesn't include CSS for pretty, minimalist formatting, but it definitely helps with my ADD.

[image]

[image]